# Querying a JSON array of objects in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a postgres db with a json data field.
The json I have is an array of objects:

```
[{"name":"Mickey Mouse","age":10},{"name":"Donald Duck","age":5}]
```

I'm trying to return values for a specific key in a JSON array, so in the above example I'd like to return the values for name.

When I use the following query I just get a NULL value returned:

```
SELECT data->'name' AS name FROM json_test
```

Im assuming this is because it's an array of objects?  Is it possible to directly address the name key?

Ultimately what I need to do is to return a count of every unique name, is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you have to *unnest* the array of json-objects first using the function (`json_array_elements` *or `jsonb_array_elements` if you have jsonb data type*), then you can access the values by specifying the key.

```
WITH json_test (col) AS (
  values (json '[{"name":"Mickey Mouse","age":10},{"name":"Donald Duck","age":5}]')
)
SELECT
  y.x->'name' "name"
FROM json_test jt, 
LATERAL (SELECT json_array_elements(jt.col) x) y

-- outputs:
name
--------------
"Mickey Mouse"
"Donald Duck"
```

To get a count of unique names, its a similar query to the above, except the count distinct aggregate function is applied to `y.x->>name`

```
WITH json_test (col) AS (
  values (json '[{"name":"Mickey Mouse","age":10},{"name":"Donald Duck","age":5}]')
)
SELECT
  COUNT( DISTINCT y.x->>'name') distinct_names
FROM json_test jt, 
LATERAL (SELECT json_array_elements(jt.col) x) y
```

It is necessary to use `->>` instead of `->` as the former (`->>`) casts the extracted value as text, which supports equality comparison (needed for distinct count), whereas the latter (`->`) extracts the value as json, which does not support equality comparison.

Alternatively, convert the `json` as `jsonb` and use `jsonb_array_elements`. `JSONB` supports the equality comparison, thus it is possible to use COUNT DISTINCT along with extraction via `->`, i.e.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT (y.x::jsonb)->'name')
```

---

updated answer for postgresql versions 12+

It is now possible to extract / unnest specific keys from a list of objects using jsonb path queries, so long as the field queried is jsonb and not json.

example:

```sql
WITH json_test (col) AS (
  values (jsonb '[{"name":"Mickey Mouse","age":10},{"name":"Donald Duck","age":5}]')
)
SELECT jsonb_path_query(col, '$[*].name') "name"
FROM json_test
-- replaces this original snippet:
-- SELECT
--   y.x->'name' "name"
-- FROM json_test jt, 
-- LATERAL (SELECT json_array_elements(jt.col) x) y
```

Comment: Not sure which version of PostgreSQL you're using, but using a `COUNT`/`GROUP BY` works fine for me using both `->` and `->>`. (Tested with version 10.)

Comment: @Bruno, `COUNT(y.x->'name')` will work, _however_, `COUNT(DISTINCT y.x->'name')` will not work because the the equality comparator is not implemented for `json` / `jsonb` types, and `count distinct` needs to check that two elements are dissimilar

Comment: I think I found out why it works for me: (a) I'm using `jsonb` (not `json`) and (b) I'm using version 10. This was implemented in version 9.4 and added to the JSON operators documentation: "*The standard comparison operators shown in Table 9.1 are available for jsonb, but not for json.*", so the equality operator does exist in this case.

Comment: @Bruno, That's an amazing find!! Thanks. I had always assumed `jsonb` didn't support the comparison operators since `json` did not. Updating answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 20):

Do like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM json_test WHERE (column_name @> '[{"name": "Mickey Mouse"}]');
```

Comment: Vote up for the simplicity ::thumbup

Comment: Is there a Postgres version where this becomes valid? I get  `ERROR: malformed array literal: "[{"name": "Mickey Mouse""}]" Detail: "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.`

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`jsonb_array_elements` (when using `jsonb`) or `json_array_elements` (when using `json`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to expand the array elements.

For example:

```
WITH sample_data_array(arr) AS (
    VALUES ('[{"name":"Mickey Mouse","age":10},{"name":"Donald Duck","age":5}]'::jsonb)
)
, sample_data_elements(elem) AS (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(arr) FROM sample_data_array
)
SELECT elem->'name' AS extracted_name FROM sample_data_elements;
```

In this example, `sample_data_elements` is equivalent to a table with a single `jsonb` column called `elem`, with two rows (the two array elements in the initial data).

The result consists of two rows (one `jsonb` column, or of type `text` if you used `->>'name'` instead):

```
 extracted_name
----------------
 "Mickey Mouse"
 "Donald Duck"
(2 rows)
```

You should them be able to group and aggregate as usual to return the count of individual names.