# How to parse a table with a JSON array field in PostgreSQL into rows?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table that contains a json array. Here is a sample of the contents of the field from:

```
SELECT json_array FROM table LIMIT 5;
```

Result:

> [{"key1":"value1"}, {"key1":"value2"}, ..., {"key2":"value3"}]
>   []
>   []
>   []{"key1":"value1"}
>   []

How can I retrieve all the values and count how many of each value was found?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.14, and I have tried the solutions here [Querying a JSON array of objects in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255641/querying-a-json-array-of-objects-in-postgres)
and the ones suggested to me by another generous stackoverflow user in my last question: [How can I parse JSON arrays in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217300/how-can-i-parse-json-arrays-in-postgresql)

I tried:

```sql
SELECT 
    value -> 'key1'
FROM
    table,
    json_array_elements(json_array);
```

which sadly does not work for me due to receiving the error:
 *cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar*
[This error happens when using a query that returns more than one row or more than one column as a scalar subquery.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-expressions.html)

Another solution I tried was:

```sql
SELECT json_array as json, (json_array->0), 
  coalesce(
    case
      when (json_array->0) IS NULL then null
      else (json_array->0->>'key1')
    end,
  'No value') AS "Value"
FROM table;
```

which only returned null values for the "Value"

Referencing [Querying a JSON array of objects in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255641/querying-a-json-array-of-objects-in-postgres) I attempted to use this solution as well:

```sql
WITH json_test (col) AS (
values (json_arrays)
)
SELECT
  y.x->'key1' "key1"
FROM json_test jt, 
LATERAL (SELECT json_array_elements(jt.col) x) y;
```

But I would need to be able to fit all the elements of the json_arrays into json_test

So far I have only attempted to list all the values in the all json arrays, but my ideal end-result for the query resembles this:

Value   | Amount
---------------
value1  |  48
value2  |  112
value3  |  93
value4  |  0

Yet again I am grateful for any help with this, thank you in advance.

Comment: I figured out the error. It was due to our json arrays in the table being saved with quotation marks around them. This prevented using any of postgresql's native json-functions on the columns data, and string manipulation was not possible without typecasting the broken json arrays first to text. I was using the sql lab tool to construct my sql queries, which didn't show the quotation marks, and lead me to believe the reason for the error was elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=0a62cb76281e51870e68007045f44483)

```
SELECT
    each.value,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    data,
    json_array_elements(json_array) elems,   -- 1
    json_each_text(elems) each               -- 2
GROUP BY each.value                          -- 3
```

1. Expand array into one row for each array element
2. split the key/value pairs into two columns
3. group by the new value column/count

Comment: Thank you again. Unfortunately this returns the error:
"cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar".

Comment: @Lauri Please check the demo and have a look what is different in your case. In my case this obviously works. Maybe your table structure is a bit different?

Comment: @Lauri Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708851/postgresql-cannot-call-json-object-keys-on-a-scalar

Comment: Thank you, this also returns "cannot call json_object_keys on a scalar". There must be some fault at my end that I haven't noticed. I am going to try to replicate my issue on fiddle and I should also go through my json column to see if there is any abnormalities causing this. I keep getting these "cannot call <function> on a scalar" messages even when I end my query with limit 1 and query an empty [] json array with the selects you created. I also double checked that the type of the column is json. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Ah no, your fiddle works everytime. I will try to see if I can recreate my error in fiddle. I will post a solution if I can find what causes this.